# awk select values with scientific notations

Tags: awk

Dear bioinformaticians,

I have a problem with awk and scientific notation of values.

I want to use awk to select rows based on the min value of $5 to keep only one ID of $1 ::

```
Chrpa1_10100    2434    PF00063 des 3.9E-21 IPR001609   
Chrpa1_10100    2434    PF03547 des 4.5E-7  IPR004776   
Chrpa1_10100    2434    PF07857 des 3.3E-7  IPR012435   
Chrpa1_10100    2434    PF13516 des 0.085   IPR001611
```

in this particular case, I want :

```
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF00063 des 3.9E-21 IPR001609
```

If I do :

```
cat file |sort -k1,1|uniq| awk -F'\t' '$5 > max[$1] { max[$1]=$5; row[$1]=$0 } END { for (i in row) print row[i] }'
```

but I want this one :

```
Chrpa1_10100 2434    PF13516 des 0.085   IPR001611
```

Thank you in advance,

Cheers

Comment: sorry, its confusiong, after the but*, I wanted to say that my command line is giving to me  this : Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF13516 des 0.085 IPR001611 but I want this  Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF00063 des 3.9E-21 IPR001609

Comment: you should just edit your question rather than commenting it :)

Answer (score 2):

> my command line is giving to me this : Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF13516 des 0.085
> IPR001611 but I want this Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF00063 des 3.9E-21
> IPR001609

Out of following numbers

```
3.9E-21 4.5E-7 3.3E-7 0.085
```

`3.9E-21` is smallest, `0.085` is biggest, this code

```
awk -F'\t' '$5 > max[$1] { max[$1]=$5; row[$1]=$0 } END { for (i in row) print row[i] }'
```

selects biggest number, hence it did find line with `0.085`. If you want `3.9E-21` you need to implement finding minimal value but remembering that while unknown mean zero is fine for finding max of positive numbers, it is not for minumum, therefore I suggest following ameloration

```
awk -F'\t' '!($1 in min)||($5 < min[$1]){ min[$1]=$5; row[$1]=$0 } END { for (i in row) print row[i] }'
```

Explanation: changed `max` to `min` and `>` to `<` and altered condition so is true if there is not key `$1` in min array or value of `$5` is smaller than value in `min` under key `$1`.

When `file.txt` content is

```
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF00063 des 3.9E-21 IPR001609
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF03547 des 4.5E-7 IPR004776
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF07857 des 3.3E-7 IPR012435
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF13516 des 0.085 IPR001611
```

then

```
awk '!($1 in min)||($5 < min[$1]){ min[$1]=$5; row[$1]=$0 } END { for (i in row) print row[i] }' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Chrpa1_10100 2434 PF00063 des 3.9E-21 IPR001609
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: hello, thank you, but it is nor working even with -F'\t', I still have 0.085 ....

Comment: i want the smallest 3.9E-21

Comment: @CarolineJuery what version of awk you are using (what is output of `awk --version`)?

Comment: thank so much, with !($1 in min)||($5 < min[$1]) its working fine :-)